# Ifelse fails in render function

Tags: r, shiny, control-flow

The following code works. The functional line of code is `p1+p2+p3+p4+show`. However, if I comment that line out and uncomment the commented lines, the app still works, but the associated map doesn't render. The error is `argument is of length zero`.

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Thanks as always!

### UI

```r
    tabPanel("US Map",
             fluidRow(
               sliderInput("daterange","Date Range",
                           min = lubridate::as_date("2022-05-01"),
                           max = lubridate::as_date("2022-12-31"),
                           value = c(lubridate::as_date("2022-05-01"),
                                     lubridate::as_date("2022-12-31"))),
               checkboxInput("tweets","Show Tweets",value = TRUE),
               checkboxInput("actions","Show Actions",value = TRUE),
               hr(),
               tmapOutput("geo2")
             ))
#> Error in tabPanel("US Map", fluidRow(sliderInput("daterange", "Date Range", : could not find function "tabPanel"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Server

```r
  output$geo2 <- renderTmap({
    
    tweets_sf %<>% filter(date>=input$daterange[1],date<=input$daterange[2])
    
    actions_sf <- actions %>%
      # filter(incident_date >= input$daterange[1],incident_date <= input$daterange[2]) %>% 
      st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat"),crs=4326) %>% 
      st_cast("POINT")
    
    tmap_mode("view")
    ## tmap mode set to plotting
    
    p1<-tm_shape(usa) +
      tm_fill("#acc480",alpha = 0.4,id = "NAME")
    p2<-tm_shape(usa) +
      tm_borders("black", lwd = .5) 
    p3<-tm_shape(actions_sf) +
      tm_text("target_type", size = 1,scale=1) +
      tm_symbols(col = "brown1",shape = "target_type",shapes = rep(5,6), 
                 size = 1,alpha=0.4, scale = .25) +
      tm_legend(show = TRUE)
    p4<-tm_shape(tweets_sf) +
      tm_text("ngram", size = 1,scale=.7) +
      tm_symbols(col = "deepskyblue1", id = "date", 
                 size = 1,alpha=0.4, scale = 0.15,palette = "RdBu") +
      tm_legend(show = TRUE)
    show<-tm_view(set.view = c(-98.5795,39.8283,4))
    
    # if(input$tweets==TRUE & input$action==TRUE){
    #   p1+p2+p3+p4+show
    # }else if(input$tweets==TRUE & input$actions==FALSE){
    #   p1+p2+p4+show
    # }else if(input$tweets==FALSE & input$actions==TRUE){
    #   p1+p2+p3+show
    # }else{p1+p2+show}
    
    p1+p2+p3+p4+show
    
  })
#> Error in renderTmap({: could not find function "renderTmap"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It would be helpful to have a *reproducible* example and an explanation of the errors in the comment lines in the code fragments you have given us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argument is of length zero` is because the left parameter of the condition is empty.

Use `DescTools::Coalesce()` (or other similar function)

```
if(DescTools::Coalesce(input$tweets),TRUE)==TRUE
 &  DescTools::Coalesce(input$actions,TRUE)==FALSE)
```

etc

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.47/topics/Coalesce

Comment: I'd never have thought of that, but it worked. Thank you.